# С# проблема с генерацией объектов

Tags: c#, .net

Прошу помочь, я не понимаю почему генерация объектов в данном отрывке кода не работает.
Есть иерархия классов Person, Student, Schoolboy в конструкторах по умолчанию все поля объектов данных классов заполняются автоматически. Все они работают, проверено на предыдущих работах с данной иерархией. Так же есть класс RandomClass в котором есть метод, который возвращает случайно сгенерированный объект одного из классов иерархии, данный класс и метод тоже работает корректно, это также проверено в предыдущей лабе. **Проблема: я генерирую случайный объект одного из классов иерархии и записываю его в лист**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**и у меня все поля всех объектов заполняются одними и теми же данными**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**при попытке отследить где возникает ошибка, я поставил точку останова в цикле**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**и о чудо все объекты сгенерировались случайно и поля различны.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Я убираю точку останова снова запускаю программу и без точки останова объекты снова заполняются одинаковыми данными**
Прошу помочь, я искренне не понимаю в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Без кода RandomClass говорить не о чем. Однако 99%, что в нем создается new Random() и из-за быстрой скорости выполнения кода получается одинаковый seed, а значит и одинаковый рэндом

Comment: Использование Thread.Sleep() решило проблему, спасибо

Comment: Это даже рядом не решение. Правильное - инициировать конструктор Random разными значениями. Используйте хотя бы такую наивную реализацию `Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());`

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом, а не скринами. И проблема за пределами показанного кода.